# Opencv2 Sample Program not working

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I am trying to get opencv2 codes working on my Ubuntu 12.04. Seems like the libraries are installed correctly.

Here is the sample code I am trying to get to work

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Read image and write to matrix - here converted to grayimage by "0"
    Mat myimage = imread ( argv[1], 0 );

    // Show it in a window
    imshow ( "MyWindowTitle", myimage);

    // Wait for a keypress ( for x [ms], 0 means infinity )
    waitKey(0);
}
```

I am compiling this code as:

```
g++ -o sample `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` sample.cpp
```

However I get the following compiler errors:

```
/tmp/cccMPtyu.o: In function `main':
imshow.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
imshow.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
imshow.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
imshow.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/cccMPtyu.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
imshow.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x2b): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/cccMPtyu.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
imshow.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[cv::Mat::release()]+0x3b): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could be the possible reason? How do I correct it?

Also can anyone suggest a good tutorial for specifically opencv2. I have programmed using opencv1 before, but seems like there have been a lot of changes.

Comment: What is the output of pkgconfig? The command string between the two ` s ?

Comment: -I/usr/include/opencv  -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the library path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBARARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

then use the command

```
g++ -o sample sample.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: I have done the unix locate on libopencv_core.so. and looks like these lib files are in /usr/lib. In this case why do I need to export LD paths? I believe these paths should already be there, isn't it?

Comment: o i see you install in default libs

Comment: yes, I installed with apt-get. Any suggestion as to how I get this working?

Comment: would you give a try of my second command as same as written.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `pkg-config` program is assuming that the library path for `opencv` `libs` in in the default path, and it is not.
try adding the `-L` option to the `gcc` line. (`-L{path to opencv libs}`)